# How to sort a field which is present inside other filed

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to sort by field first_name.

```
{  
 "_index":"data1",
 "_type":"data1",
 "_id":"190204051110",
 "_score":1,
 "_source":{  
  "hello_info":{  
     "first_name":"abc"
  },
  "created":"2019-02-04T05:11:10.058470",
  "modified":"2019-02-04T11:10:47.122065"
 }
}
```

Comment: query I tried for created time it works good. {
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must":[ {
                    "exists": {
                        "field": "hello_info.first_name"
                    }
                }
                ]
            }
        }
        ,
        "_source":["created",
        "modified",
        "hello_info.first_name"],
        "sort":[ {
            "created": {
                "order": "asc"
            }
        }
        ]
    }

Comment: but for first_name,
    {
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must":[ {
                    "exists": {
                        "field": "hello_info.first_name"
                    }
                }
                ]
            }
        }
        ,
        "_source":["created",
        "modified",
        "hello_info.first_name"],
        "sort":[ {
            "first_name": {
                "order": "asc"
            }
        }
        ]
    }

Comment: {
        "type": "query_shard_exception", "reason": "No mapping found for [hello_info.first_name] in order to sort on", "index_uuid": "ZJqoK5VOTA2EtR5aP18x-A", "index": "ana-kraft"
    }

Comment: Please some one help me to sort first_name from above

Comment: can you add your relevant comments in the question body instead ? ( You can edit the question ) for more readability. Plus in order to help you we will need the mapping of your index. Plus it seems the first_name ordered query you posted is not the good one since you try to sort on "first_name" and the exeception is about "hello_info.first_name" field. Thx